# SharePoint 2010 workflow Impersonation alternative

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2010, office-365, designer-workflow, ms-flow

As we have Impersonation step available in SharePoint 2010 workflows, what alternative I can have to implement the same.
I have O365 SharePoint site. I looked into the MS Flow, but did not find anything which can be used as replacement for 2010 workflow Impersonation.

Kindly suggest options. As there are various kinds of permission levels are updated across item level using this Impersonation step in 2010 workflow, what can be used to replace the same.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

My typical way around this is to use a "service account" that has the needed permissions in the Flow connection.  The down side is that the "service account" has to have a Flow and SharePoint license in M365.

Comment: but i have to change the permissions on that item like modifying some SP group permissions and user permissions on that item once it is created. I do not find any step to perform this action

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below articles to change item permissions in SharePoint online using flow:

https://noellawlor.wordpress.com/2018/01/18/setting-sharepoint-item-list-permissions-with-flow/

https://collab365.community/sharepoint-item-permissions-using-flow-part-1/